# create object for hold data in entity-framework

Tags: entity-framework

I use entity-framework in my project i want to define and object that the user entry data

And finally insert the all data which user entry in database

But i need an object that hold the data before final insert(like dataset)

please advise me

Comment: Dont really know what your question is

Comment: possible duplicate of [build an object in entityframework like dataset in ADO.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323841/build-an-object-in-entityframework-like-dataset-in-ado-net)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be best that you have a further read of the entity framework.  There are many examples, articles, threads, etc regarding EF4 and it's predecessors that should help you along your way.

To address what I think you mean by your question, you can take a look at using repository patterns.  There are many variations, but here's a link to get you started:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx

I hope that helps.